# iOS App‘s UIView Animation suddenly become very fast

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I worked on a App using UIView's anmation function(such as [UIView animateWithDuration:], [UIView beginAnimations] ... [UIView commitAnimations]). When I debug it on iPad, it runs ok, but after server hours later, the Animation suddenly become very fast, it's duration is less than what it is.
  I wonder what happened, and I've no idea.
  Can anyone help me out?
Code used 1

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"showShine" context:view];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animFinished:finished:context:)]; 
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f]; 
view.frame = CGRectMake(center.x - F_WIDTH / 2, center.y - F_HEIGHT / 2, F_WIDTH, F_HEIGHT); [self.view addSubview:view]; 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Code used 2

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:DURIATION 
animations:^{ 
[aniView setFrame:rtDestAfter]; 
} 
completion:^(BOOL finised){ 
[self animationFinished:stoken]; 
[stoken release]; 
} 
];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Post the code you use for animation...

Comment: <pre><code>[UIView beginAnimations:@"showShine" context:view]; // [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(shineAniStop:)]; [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animFinished:finished:context:)]; [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f]; view.frame = CGRectMake(center.x - F_WIDTH / 2, center.y - F_HEIGHT / 2, F_WIDTH, F_HEIGHT); [self.view addSubview:view]; [UIView commitAnimations];</code></pre>

Comment: edit the question and include code there

Comment: Why don't you use block-based animations instead of the old, pre-iOS4 procedural animations?

Comment: When I used the following method, I met the same question:[UIView animateWithDuration:SWITCH_APP_DURIATION
                     animations:^{
                          [aniView setFrame:rtDestAfter];
                      }
    
                     completion:^(BOOL finised){
                         [vc setFrame:rtDestAfter];
                         [self setAppStatus:stoken appStatus:APP_SHOWN];
                         [self animationFinished:stoken];
                         [stoken release];
                     }
     
     ];

Comment: What you mean by this animation? Let me know how your animation should be.

Comment: By any chance, does your code use `CATransation` somewhere? (That's the underlying engine to `UIView` animations, and if you screw something up in there, it could have an effect on your animations)

Answer (score 0):

Use block code for this purpose

```
animateWithDuration:animations:completion
```

eg

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
     animations:^{view.alpha = 0.0;}
     completion:^(BOOL finished){ [view removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

OR

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

**EDIT**

What is the add subview method do anyway in the animation block .First add the subview with proper frame outside/before block and implement the animation within the animation block

Comment: I wonder how it happened? What reason will result in such problem.

Comment: Hi, by reading and debuging code, I found after I removed a view from superview and set it to be nil, then the problem occurred. And the view removed has nothing to do with the animation. After I comment the removing code, then the problem disappear. I wonder how it happened. Please help me out. Thx